# Find all simple paths between two sets

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, path-finding

I am working with an algorithm which resembles the [all simple paths](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/allSimplePaths.html) problem, with two twists.

1. Instead of just searching for paths between two unique nodes, I want to find paths between two disjoint sets of nodes; {sources} and {destinations}.
2. I am only interested in paths without detours. If I find one path (A-B-D), then I am not interested in (A-B-C-D), since it will always be worse than the former. The weight of each edge is unknown at parse-time but they are always positive.

I know that this can be achieved by running a DFS algorithm of every {sources} and {destinations} combination, followed by a removal of all detours. This, however, I imagine would be very slow.

Is there any way to achieve this in one algorithm? Or most of it?

**EDIT**

Please note that I have no clue of the edge weights. Assume that we find the following three paths (where each letter is an edge, not a node): (A-B-C-G), (A-B-G) and (A-C-D-E-F-G). The first path can be removed, since the second path is a subset of it. But B might very well be more expensive than C, D, E and F combined! So in this case I must know both these paths.

I'm not looking for the shortest path, I'm looking for all paths that does not contain a detour.

Comment: by disjoint set of node do you mean a bijection (one node from source correspond on one node from dest) or cartesian product (each node from sources to all nodes from dest)

Comment: I mean that they do not have any nodes in common.

Comment: yes I get that. does {1,2} and {3,4} lead to looking for simple path for `(1,3), (2,4)` or for `(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)`

Comment: Ah, sorry! The latter; (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)

Comment: How do you reconcile your 2nd bullet point with your edit? If you have no clue about edge weights then `B-D` may have a higher cost than the combined cost of `B-C-D` so the longer path (by number of nodes) may be the lower cost path.

Comment: I know that the weights are positive by definition (2nd bullet), but I don't know the exact value. In your example, if (B-C-D) would be less expensive than (B-D), then the weight of C must be negative.

Comment: You appear to be giving the vertices weight not the edges - you state in point 2 that the weight of the **edges** is always positive.

Comment: `The weight of each edge is ... always positive` - If the edge from vertex `B` to vertex `C` has weight 1 and from vertex `C` to vertex `D` has weight 2 then the path `B-C-D` has total weight 3. Now if the edge from vertex `B` directly to vertex `D` (path `B-D`) has weight 4 then you get the situation where `B-C-D` has a cost of 3 and `B-D` has a cost of 4 - the longer path is lower cost.